# JS скрипт/div элемент (предварительный текст до загрузки)

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы при загрузке на странице JS скрипта/div элемента, был текст "Загрузка..." а после появления самого JS скрипта, он исчезал?

Comment: Это называется прелоадер. В поисковике много различных готовых вариантов. Берите любой на своё усмотрение

Comment: Бред какой-то вы тут написали. Рекомендую вам [посмотреть вот этот ролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CIv6W7_t6k), вроде все доступно объясняют, как что делается. Не помню если ли там текст "загрузка", но принцип тот же. Также хочу добавить, что в вашем вопросе не хватает [минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Просто за вас, вряд-ли найдется доброволец все сделать. Ваши усилия тоже нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Появление и исчезновение элемента через JavaScript делается так

```js
function showHide() {
  document.getElementById("loader").classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById("loader").classList.remove("hidden");
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("loader").classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#loader {
  margin: 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hide()">Спрятать</button>
<button onclick="show()">Показать</button>
<button onclick="showHide()">Переключить</button>

<div id="loader">Идёт загрузка</div>
```